# django request.session.get("name", False) - What does this code mean?

Tags: python, django

I am using the following code :

```
if request.session.get("name",False):
```

Can anyone please tell me what the above code does? What I assume is, if there is "name" in session it returns True, otherwise, it returns False. I'm confused with my code so I posted this question here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `session` has a key in it with the value `"name"` it returns *the value associated with that key* (which might well be `False`), otherwise (if there is no key named "name") it returns `False`.

The `session` is a dictionary-like type so the best place to get documenation on the [`get` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is in the Python docs for the standard library.  The short of the matter is that `get` is shorthand for the following:

```
if "name" in request.session:
    result = request.session["name"]
else:
    result = False

if result:
    # Do something
```

Comment: I am sorry but i got confused with the 'which might well be' part(not a native speaker).So in the case of request.session.get('cart_id'," ") if there is no key cart_id in the dict it would return an empty string right?

Comment: No, it would return `None` (assuming it sticks with the same defaults as a normal Python dictionary).  But it doesn't matter, since both an empty string and `None` are falsey values.

Comment: I just did an edit of the comment.. Then whats the argument after the comma for?

Comment: In your altered comment it would return an empty string :-)

Answer (score 3):

As per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get) the 2nd argument of the get method is the default. So "request.session.get("name",False):" statement returns the value of the 'name' items if it exists in the session if it doesn't then a default of False is returned.

Comment: Although you are completely correct, the accepted answer already explains this quite well :)

Comment: FWIW, I found this explanation easier to follow and more succinct.